# Setting cache expires for images in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How can I set cache expires never for images only in laravel 4.1? The documentation is really sparse on this topic.

Has anyone figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 return Response::view('some_template')->header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
```

Comment: I dont think that would work. I want to set it for all images across all templates. Also, I want it to set it to 6 months or so.